# Validating Input in javascript didn't work

Tags: javascript, html

why this simple javascript code didn't run properly 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBXKQY
html

```
 <form id="scoreForm" name="scoreForm"  onsubmit="validateForm();">


            <label for="score">Score:</label>
            <input id="score" name="score" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />


    </form>
```

js

```
  function validateForm() {

            var score = document.getElementById("score").value;
            var scoreReg = /^\s*(\+|-)?\d+\s*$/;

            if (score.match(scoreReg))
            { alert("the score pass"); return false; }

        }
```

i just need to perform validation that is beyond the capabilities of the HTML5 input attributes.

Comment: How about you explain what you want your validation to do?

Comment: it's just for learning purpose as i'm new to javascript and i just want to check a specific input based in pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

instead of

```
onsubmit="validateForm();"
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/papajh5c/1/)

Comment: your demo works fine but let's declare that the error wasn't in onsubmit , it was in function (if statement) if (score.match(scoreReg))
      { 
          alert("the score pass"); 
          return true; 
      }
      return false;
thanks for your help and code

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="scoreForm" name="scoreForm">
    <label for="score">Score:</label>
    <input id="score" name="score" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('scoreForm').addEventListener('submit', validateForm);

function validateForm(ev) {

  var scoreVal = +document.getElementById('score').value;

  if (scoreVal < 10) {
    alert('Sorry your score is too low!');
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/ferahl/pen/GgGpLd

Notes:

Better to not really use IDs for anything, use classes, query them with `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

The `+` you see there converts to a number (it's shorthand)

Better to use "unobtrusive" javascript - I add the event handler in JS using `addEventListener`

`preventDefault` stops the form submitting. There is also another useful function called `stopPropagation` which you can look into. Return false does both - it is better to have an awareness of which or both you want to do.

Comment: yeah , this works and i can call it's best practice too .thank you for your time to explain these things

Answer (score 0):

**call validateForm() method here**

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validateForm();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some bug in code pen

you can try in w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onsubmit